# Programming language-like syntax for nested lists

Tags: nesting, comma-separated-list

Consider the following code that simply nests two lists using the `\ForEach` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forarray}

\newcommand{\demo}[1]
{
\begin{itemize}
     \ForEach{.}{\item \thislevelitem}{#1}
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\demo
{
     1.
     \demo
     {
         21.
         22
     }.
     3
}
\end{document}
```

How should I modify the `\demo` command such that if I remove the `.` just before the `3`, the output remains the same?

The motivation is to replicate an usual programming language syntax where statements are ended with `.` and control sequences ( such as `\demo` ) are enclosed between brackets (without a final `.`).

Feel free to use your preferred list processing tool instead of `forarray` but please try to avoid `Expl3` syntax as long as possible.

Comment: By removing the `.` before the `3`, how  is it that you're going to distinguish between a continuation of a paragraph after a list and a new list entry for the outer list?

Comment: Whenever a demo group is closed, the following text should always be placed in a new item entry.

Comment: I cannot write up a full blown answer right now, but given your latest comment, naively I would think of creating a counter to track the level of nesting.  If the nesting is greater than zero, I would have the `\demo` macro throw out an `\item`.  But, this approach has its own problems such as with `\demo{1. \demo{21. 22}}` where you wouldn't want an spurious `\item` showing up.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `forarray` package; so, I don't know whether the macros it provides are expandable or not.  If expandability is not an issue, you could use `\@ifnextchar` to test the next character to see whether or not to toss out an extra `\item`.  If no one has posted their own solution to this later tonight, then I'll write up something that might work for you, but it won't be for several more hours.

Comment: According to the `forarray` user manual: The command  `\ForEachX` processes the list of items in the same way as the command `\ForEach`. However, it expands its third argument, a token containing
the actual list, before processing it.

Comment: You should define `\newcommand\demo[1]{\@demo#1\@something}`  And then you can later use `\futurelet` to grab the token after the next and then run a test on whether you have two adjacent `\@something`.  Now, if `\@something` is not defined as a macro, then that will just result in an error.  Nevertheless, that's the main thrust of the idea for this naive approach.

Comment: I don't believe my idea is going to work.  I think part of the problem is that `forarray` is inserting and wrapping its own content around the passed arguments.  My thoughts right now is that you could try parsing the content of `\demo` twice: the first time to insert the missing punctuation, the second time to parse with `forarray` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough draft for a solution.  I believe this can be cleaned up a bit, but here's what I've come up with so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forarray}

\makeatletter
\def\@demo@query{\relax}%%

\newcounter{@demo@level@cnt}
\newcommand{\demo}[1]{\@demo#1\@demo@query\@nil\@demo@follow@up}
\def\@demo#1\@nil{%%
  \stepcounter{@demo@level@cnt}%%
  \begin{itemize}
    \ForEach{.}{\item \thislevelitem}{#1}%%
}

\def\@demo@follow@up{%%
  \@ifnextchar\@demo@query
  {\@demo@close}
  {\@demo@continue}}

\def\@demo@continue{%%
  \@demo@close
  \ifnum\the@demo@level@cnt>0 %%
    \item
  \fi
}

\def\@demo@close{%%
  \end{itemize}%%
  \addtocounter{@demo@level@cnt}{-1}%%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\demo
{
     1.
     \demo
     {
         21.
         22
     }
     3.4
}

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\demo
{
     1.
     \demo
     {
         21.
         22
     }}


\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\demo
{
     1.
     \demo
     {
         21.
         22
     }   
}

\end{document}
```

The key is creating some wrapper code to get around the wrapper code introduced by `forarray`.  Hence

```
\@demo#1\@demo@query\@nil\@demo@follow@up
```

The last command

```
\@demo@follow@up
```

will be followed by

```
\@demo@query
```

only if there is no further code to examine.

**To assist in seeing what's happening**
consider the following *moot* code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\demo[1]{\@demo#1?\@nil!}
\def\@demo#1\@nil{[\another{#1}]}
\def\another#1{<<#1>>}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\demo{1.\demo{21.22}3.4}\par
\demo{1.\demo{21.22}}

\end{document}
```

The macro `\another` wraps its arguments with `<<` and `>>` in a manner similar to what `forarray`s macros do.  The question mark plays the role of `\@demo@query` and the exclamation point that of `\@demo@follow@up`.  As in the real solution above, `!` only precedes `?` when there is no continuation code for `\ForEach` to consider.

[image]

Comment: This works. Great job.